# Complexity of computation of ANF-form (Zhegalkin polynomial)

Tags: complexity-classes, polynomials

Let $f: \mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2$ be a boolean function.
Consider $f$ as a multilinear polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (algebraic normal form or Zhegalkin polynomial).

How hard is to define the degree of $f$ if $f$ is given as truth-table?

It is  easy to see that this can be done in polynomial time, but does the corresponding decision problem is P-complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ff{\mathbb F_2}\def\sset{\subseteq}$Given the truth-table $\langle f(a):a\in\ff^k\rangle$ of a function $f\colon\ff^k\to\ff$, its multilinear expansion can be explicitly computed by
$$\begin{align*}f(x)&=\sum_{a\in\ff^k}f(a)\prod_{i\in[k]}(x_i+a_i+1)\\
&=\sum_{a\in\ff^k}f(a)\sum_{I\sset[k]}\prod_{i\in I}x_i\prod_{i\notin I}(a_i+1)\\
&=\sum_{a\in\ff^k}f(a)\sum_{a^{-1}(1)\sset I\sset[k]}\prod_{i\in I}x_i\\
&=\sum_{I\sset[k]}\prod_{i\in I}x_i\underbrace{\sum_{\substack{a\in\ff^k\\a^{-1}(1)\sset I}}f(a)}_{f_I},
\end{align*}$$
where $a^{-1}(1)=\{i\in[k]:a_i=1\}$. That is, each coefficient $f_I$ is a sum (modulo $2$) of certain entries of the truth table; thus, we can compute $\langle f_I:I\sset[k]\rangle$ using a uniform $\mathrm{AC}^0[2]$ circuit, and then for a given $d$,
$$\operatorname{deg}(f)\ge d\iff\bigvee_{|I|\ge d}f_I$$
is also computable in uniform $\mathrm{AC}^0[2]$.

On the other hand, the problem is $\mathrm{AC}^0[2]$-complete: by the expansion above, $f_{[k]}$ is the parity of the whole truth table (considered as a string); observe that $f_{[k]}=1\iff\operatorname{deg}(f)\ge k$.

Comment: It seems like if $d$ is sufficiently large (so that the OR only ranges over a polylog number of different subsets) then the problem is in $CC^0[2p]$ for any prime $p \neq 2$ as well, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but this is applicable only to a few values of $d$. I suppose polylog means polylogarithmic in the size of the input, which is $2^k$, i.e., polynomial in $k$. Even so, the number of the sets is roughly $k^{k-d}$, hence it is polynomial in $k$ only if $d=k-O(1)$.